# php variable not recognised.

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have the following php script where the user can rate a player from his Android phone and post that data in my server.

So:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require "init.php";
  header('Content-type: application/json');

  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  $id = isset($_POST['player_id']);
  $user_id = isset($_POST['User_Id']);
  $best_player = isset($_POST['player']);
  $rate = isset($_POST['rating']);

  if($id && $user_id && $best_player && $rate){

    $sql_query = "insert into rating_players_table values('$id','$best_player','$rate','$user_id');";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){

        $don = array('result' =>"success","message"=>"Επιτυχής πρόσθεση παίχτη");
    }       
   }else if(!$best_player){

        $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Insert player name");

    }else if(!$rate){

        $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Rate player");

    }
 echo json_encode($don);

?>
```

However I get a message saying the $don variable inside the echo is not recognised.

The Android code that sends data is:

```
private void ratingPlayer(final String player, final int rating,final String UserId) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL.URL_BEST_PLAYERS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Best player response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("fail")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register urls
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("player_id", "");
            params.put("User_Id", UserId);
            params.put("player", player);
            params.put("rating", String.valueOf(rating));
            return params;
        }
    };
      // Adding request to request queue
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
   }
```

where

```
final String player, final int rating,final String UserId
```

the values I put in my edit texts fields in the Android phone.

What could be wrong?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: If the first if-statement is true but the one inside is false then `$don` is never initialized

Comment: I put the echo json_encode($don); inside if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){..},but I get nothing.

Comment: Yes, it will never get that far. Look at my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more correct

```
$id_isSet = isset($_POST['player_id']);
$user_id_isSet = isset($_POST['User_Id']);
$best_player_isSet = isset($_POST['player']);
$rate_isSet = isset($_POST['rating']);

if($id_isSet && $user_id_isSet && $best_player_isSet && $rate_isSet){

    $id = $_POST["player_id"];
    $user_id = $_POST['User_Id'];
    $best_player = $_POST['player'];
    $rate = $_POST['rating'];

    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO rating_players_table VALUES('$id','$best_player','$rate','$user_id');";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){

        $don = array('result' =>"success","message"=>"Επιτυχής πρόσθεση παίχτη");
    }       
   }else if(!$best_player){

        $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Insert player name");

    }else if(!$rate){

        $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Rate player");

    }
 echo json_encode($don);

?>
```

If you echo out `isset($_POST["id"])` and it is true you will print "1" and not the actual post value

Comment: $id = $_POST["id"];
    $user_id = $_POST['User_Id'];
    $best_player = $_POST['player'];
    $rate = $_POST['rating'];

Comment: all the above posts are not recognised:(

Comment: Do you mean that isset() is false for all?

Comment: Sorry, it shall of course be `$id = $_POST["player_id"]` (exactly the same as in the isset -functions